# How to Loop over different type variables, randomize and concatenate them?

Tags: sql, plsql

I came across a situation where I have to create a procedure for our existing database. For an example:

SQL database have firstname, lastname and dateOfBirth and an id field. Id will be created using the combination of firstName, lastName and dateOfBirth as it will give the user choice as: ('James','Borg','10-11-2027')-> system will show choice like:

```
james_borg
james_12
james_borg_12
borg_12
borg_james
borg_james_12
```

I have done so far like this without the loop. But I don't how to approach

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GEN_LOGIN_ID
  (O_FNAME IN EMPLOYEE.FNAME%TYPE, 
   O_LNAME IN EMPLOYEE.LNAME%TYPE, 
   O_BDATE IN     EMPLOYEE.BDATE%TYPE)

IS
N_NUM NUMBER(20);
N_ID VARCHAR2(60); 
BEGIN

N_NUM:=(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, O_BDATE))/12;
N_ID:=CONCAT(O_FNAME,O_LNAME);
N_ID:=CONCAT(N_ID,N_NUM);
INSERT INTO POSSIBLE_IDS(ID) VALUES(N_ID);

COMMIT;


END;
```

If I call the procedure now it gives

```
 DECLARE
O_FNAME EMPLOYEE.FNAME%TYPE;
O_LNAME EMPLOYEE.LNAME%TYPE;
O_BDATE  EMPLOYEE.BDATE%TYPE;
BEGIN
GEN_LOGIN_ID('James','Borg','10-11-2027');

END;
```

The result comes JamesBorg-12. Need some assistant please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any randomization here but I can see a pattern. How about assigning those patterns in variables or in an array then insert those values in your table using forall? Here's another version of your code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GEN_LOGIN_ID
    (O_FNAME IN EMPLOYEE.FNAME%TYPE, 
     O_LNAME IN EMPLOYEE.LNAME%TYPE, 
     O_BDATE IN     EMPLOYEE.BDATE%TYPE)

  IS
     N_NUM NUMBER(20);
     N_ID VARCHAR2(60); 
     type myarray  is table of varchar2(250) index by pls_integer;
     arrayofnames myarray;
  BEGIN
     N_NUM:=(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, O_BDATE))/12;

     arrayofnames(1):= O_FNAME || '_' || O_LNAME;
     arrayofnames(2):= arrayofnames(1) || '_' || N_NUM;
     arrayofnames(3):= O_FNAME || '_' || N_NUM;

     arrayofnames(4):= O_LNAME || '_' || O_FNAME;
     arrayofnames(5):= arrayofnames(4) || '_' || N_NUM;
     arrayofnames(6):= O_LNAME || '_' || N_NUM;
     FORALL A IN 1..arrayofnames.count
        INSERT INTO POSSIBLE_IDS(ID) VALUES(arrayofnames(a));
     COMMIT;
  END;
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. Thanks bro. I wish I could give a thumbs up.